# Google Chrome custom theme not working in incognito mode

Tags: windows, google-chrome, themes, private-browsing

How to set some other theme in incognito mode? Currently bar is so dark, I can't clearly see anything. This is what I used to use:

1. In experimental (chrome://flags/) I enabled "Allow widgets to inherit native theme from its parent widget" function.
2. I installed [plain](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/plain/ajpcdipecmmhmhfchegpaflpjkmceiip) theme.

Starting today, it stopped working. After every problematic update I always managed to find some workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me custom themes also stopped working in incognito mode today.
They already stopped working some weeks/months ago and I was able to fix it with the #inherit-native-theme-from-parent-widget flag set to "Enabled"

I was able to get them working again by setting the flag [chrome://flags/#incognito-brand-consistency-for-desktop](http://chrome://flags/#incognito-brand-consistency-for-desktop) to "Disabled". After that I was able to return [chrome://flags/#inherit-native-theme-from-parent-widget](http://chrome://flags/#inherit-native-theme-from-parent-widget) to "Default" and themes seem to work again in Incognito mode.

Comment: Works like a charm, once again I'm able to use google chrome without going blind. Until the next update. :)

Comment: These options seem to have disappeared as of today.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome://flags search for

"Enable Incognito brand consistency in desktop."

Set this flag to disabled. Then the incognito theme is what you defined for non incognito mode.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).