# Google Chrome (100.0.4896.60) custom themes not working in incognito mode

Tags: windows, google-chrome, themes, private-browsing

Starting today, custom themes in incognito mode stopped working. Basically, problem is exactly the same as [in my old question](https://superuser.com/questions/1697688/google-chrome-custom-theme-not-working-in-incognito-mode), but solution accepted there is not working anymore. Since I can't open old question: is there any way to make custom themes work in incoginto mode?

Comment: Sadly I have exact same problem and non of the previous flags that fixed it exist :/

Comment: Facing the same issue. I tried to fix it by changing the flags that might be related to theme or incognito but none of them work. The issue is that chrome is inheriting the theme/mode from the operating system (Windows 10 in my case). Changing/selecting an accent color from the Colors settings (under personalization) in Windows changed the frame color of the incognito windows in Chrome. I am using it as a temporary solution until a proper solution is found.